# What is the best way to save data in cron file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

I have a multistore website. Every store has a different language.
When I save data by running a cron file.

It saves the data in the English language but data does not save as per multilanguage. How to solve it?

Comment: please provide us the line of code that saves the data. are you translating it in your code?